# What is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError . I have written a QuickSort Code on Gfg. Need to get the clear explanation

Tags: java, runtime-error, quicksort

So this is the code for quickSort that I wrote but i am getting a Runtime error
I have done a dry run and I am not able to find any sort of error but i am getting this runtime error

```
class Solution
{
    
    static void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {   
        if(low<high){
            int pivot = partition(arr, low, high);`enter code here`
            quickSort(arr,low,pivot-1);
            quickSort(arr,pivot+1,high);
        }
        
    }
    static int partition(int arr[], int low, int high)
    {
       
        int pivot = arr[0];
        
        while(low<high){
            while(arr[low]<=pivot){
                low++;
            }
            
            while(arr[high]>pivot){
                high--;
            }
            
            if(low<high){
                int temp = arr[high];
                arr[high] = arr[low];
                arr[low] = temp; 
            }
        }
        
        int temp = arr[high];
        arr[high] = pivot;
        pivot = temp;
        
        return high;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your recursive calls to `quickSort` are not reaching a termination condition: every time a method is invoked the stack is used to push information (parameters, return addr, etc) and so a non terminating recursion eventually causes stack to overflow.  Also, look at your `int pivot = arr[0]` - you sure that is correct?

Comment: For recursive algorithms to work you need to work on smaller and smaller parts of the data.  If you don’t your stack will overflow.  Time to check in the debugger where your dry run differs from reality.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I wrote the code for merge sort and and i am getting the runtime error java.lang.StackOverflowError. I solved this runtime error by round brackets "()"

I was trying to find the mid of the array by

```
 int mid=start+end/2; //it was showing StackOverflowError
```

But when i placed start and end inside round brackets than it run properly without any error

```
int mid=(start+end)/2; //No error
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).